# Windows showing effect in WPF

Tags: wpf

in android based apps all windows open with a effect like it grows first with fade in effect.
so it feel like transfer effect. so is there any way to achieve this effect in wpf when window shows. please help me with code if possible.

thanks

Comment: Do you want the whole window to grow or the content within the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here is the simplest. The WindowOn storyboard adjusts the opacity of the window and is triggered when the window is loaded. You can use Expression Blend to modify the storyboard to add the grow effect you are looking for.

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowOn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.4"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="0.805"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.995"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowOn}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="root">
</Grid>
```